# Android Studio - Error:(11) Tag <uses-permission> attribute name has invalid character '/'

Tags: android, android-manifest, user-permissions

I get this error after entering the string "YOUR LICENSE KEY FOR THIS APPLICATION" for the new version of an app.

Without the key the app works perfectly and there are no other problems or mistakes.

THE ERROR: **Error:(11) Tag  attribute name has invalid character '/'.**

The string in the manifest is this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />
```

I tried to remove "/", but they are part of the KEY copied to the developer console.

There is a solution for this issue?

MANIFEST

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.myname.appname.hmapp"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.1" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="KEY" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.myname.appname.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: We'd need code to solve this, but it sounds like a typo in your strings file.

Comment: Please post the entire manifest that is giving you trouble.

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in your permission´s definition, your error was solved, this is a common problem, just go to Problems Tab and delete the error message then try to run again your project.

Comment: The problem is still here, after I enter the KEY.
In the KEY there are the symbols mentioned in the error "/" KEY however, are part of the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
```